# How to print a list of regex matches using variables and asterisk

Tags: bash, glob

I have this list of files:

```
perspectium-02-16-2019-1.log.gz  perspectium-07-27-2019-3.log.gz  perspectium-10-18-2019-1.log.gz
perspectium-07-27-2019-1.log.gz  perspectium-10-16-2019-1.log.gz  perspectium-10-18-2019-2.log.gz
perspectium-07-27-2019-2.log.gz  perspectium-10-17-2019-1.log.gz  perspectium-10-18-2019-3.log.gz
```

I have calculated one date:

```
d=$(date -d '-1 day' '+%m-%d-%Y')
```

I want to delete those files that matches the condition:

```
perspectium-$d-*.log.gz
```

But if I make an echo of this, it will print the asterisk literally, so It wont match any file:

```
perspectium-10-17-2019-*.log.gz
```

Can you please give me some clue?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: run `set +f` before doing echo

Comment: please be very careful when you combine any `rm` command with glob-star, it's one of the fastest ways to wreck your whole day...

Comment: How did you 'make the echo'? with quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following:

```
output=`ls perspectium-$d-*.log.gz`
echo $output
```

or

```
for file in perspectium-$d-*.log.gz
do
echo $file
done;
```

or just do without quotes:

```
echo perspectium-$d-*.log.gz
```

But as already said, care about possible issues with incorrect matching.

Here is output for you case:

```
[root@pro-sip tmp]# d=10-18-2019
[root@pro-sip tmp]# ls perspectium-$d-*.log.gz
perspectium-10-18-2019-1.log.gz  perspectium-10-18-2019-2.log.gz
[root@pro-sip tmp]# for i in  perspectium-$d-*.log.gz  
> do
> echo $i
> done;
perspectium-10-18-2019-1.log.gz
perspectium-10-18-2019-2.log.gz
[root@pro-sip tmp]# echo perspectium-$d-*.log.gz
perspectium-10-18-2019-1.log.gz perspectium-10-18-2019-2.log.gz
```

Comment: As I have been scolded many times for parsing the output of `ls` myself,  I think that the  first option might not be a good idea. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: It just example. Works any method without quotes.